# Sharing iOS custom url links

Tags: ios, url, sharing

I have a Mobile App with a custom url scheme registered. The App also has social sharing enabled to allow users to share deep links within the App on Facebook, Twitter and email.

My question related to this is how to handle situations cleanly where this custom iOS url is opened on a non-ios device like a PC or a Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Detect the device and change the URL scheme based on that device.  If you're using HTML you can use a jQuery plugin.  See this link: [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery)